# My own website as default website on IIS 7

Tags: iis-7

Is it possible to set my own website as default website I mean whenever I type in browser localhost(from local PC) or IP address from remote. I found a idea where I can delete Default site from IIS then my website can automatically become Default website but I dont want to that method...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just copy the bindings for default website to your website, then change the bindings for default web site (for example, to another port, or a different host header).